# How to read result in function A from function B

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two postgres  function. Function A is calling function B which return 2 record of varchar type.

**Function A**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(
 IN r1 character varying,
 IN r2 character varying,
 OUT code character varying,
 OUT msg character varying)

 RETURNS record AS
 $BODY$

 BEGIN  

 perform function B(r1,r2);

 END; $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

By doing

```
 select * from function A ('r1', 'r2')
```

I got void column code and msg.

Running Function A, Function B is working fine and return code and msg. How can I read this two return value from Function A?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing `PERFORM` the result of your `SELECT` is being discarded which is not what we're looking for.

If you have your function declared with `OUT` parameters you need to fill them with values using

```
SELECT ... INTO ...
```

So the way to do it is to obtain values coming out from `B` function and then fill your output parameters with them like:

```
SELECT * INTO code, msg FROM B(r1, r2);
```

That said your function will look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A(
 IN r1 character varying,
 IN r2 character varying,
 OUT code character varying,
 OUT msg character varying)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
BEGIN  
  SELECT * INTO code, msg FROM B(r1, r2);
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And you should call it like:

```
SELECT * FROM A('first_arg', 'second_arg');
```

Notes:

- Rethink if [`VOLATILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) is what you really need. You may be ok with just `STABLE` depending on the `B` function code. This may speed things up a bit
- To shorten your data type declaration, `character varying` is the same as `varchar`. Consider using it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Truly helpfull!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT INTO` as was mentioned before - but this statement is designed for not simple selects (has `FROM` clause). Using `SELECT INTO` just for taking result of two or more out variables functions can have performance impacts. Is better to use composite variable or record variable and assign command. Just:

```
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  r := B(r1, r2);
  RAISE NOTICE 'code: %, message: %', r.code, r.message;
  ...
```